# exit code from a builtin shell command

Tags: shell, development

I'm writing a custom shell and I want to run a shell script with my own shell. I'm trying to check if the less program is installed and if it is, use the less program otherwise use `more`. However, my shell didn't have the `type` builtin so I had to create it in order to check if less is installed.

```
int do_type(int argc, const char **argv) {
    bool found = false;
    char *curr_path;
    char *path;
    char *path_strdup;
    char *path_value;
    char *pathValue;
    pid_t pid;
    pathValue = getenv("PATH");
    path_strdup = strdup(pathValue);
    if (path_strdup == NULL) {
        perror("strdup");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    path_value = strtok(path_strdup, ":");
    path = path_value;
    while (path && !found) {
        if ((curr_path = malloc(strlen(path) + sizeof(argv[1]))) != NULL) {
            if (curr_path == NULL) {
                fprintf(stderr, "malloc failed!\n");

            }
            strcpy(curr_path, path);
            strcat(curr_path, argv[1]);
            if (file_exist(curr_path)) {
                found = true; // we found the program
            }
            //free(curr_path);
            path = strtok(NULL, ":");
        } else {
            fprintf(stderr, "malloc failed!\n");
            return false;
        }
    }
    if (found)
        printf("%s\n", curr_path, found);
    else
        printf("%s: not found\n", argv[1]);
    return 1;
}
```

The aboce code will find the `less` program if it is installed if I run the code in my shell:

```
$ type /blaha
/blaha: not found
$ type /less
/usr/bin/less
$ type /godoc
/usr/local/go/bin/godoc
$
```

Now I wonder how to perform the check. I've written this script that my shell should execute.

```
type less > /dev/null
printenv|grep $1|$PAGER
```

My shell also has the functionality of accepting a conditional `if` statement so if I can use an exit code 0 or 1 from `do_type` with my if statement then I can set the `PAGER` variable to less or more and the whole thing should work. But what should the exit code be for the `type` builtin? Is it 0 for found (success) and 1 for not found or the other way around? Is there anything else I should think of?

Comment: Does this highly software-development-specific question just boil down to **"What does the exit status of `type` signify?"**  If so you should cut out the verbiage.  It is borderline off-topic as written.

Comment: I don't understand what the question is here. We don't do programming questions here. If you're looking for a review of your working code, try [codereview.se]. If you have a specific coding problem (I don't see one here), ask on [so].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### return value

I see that you're using `EXIT_FAILURE` in your code, therefore you're including `stdlib.h`.  In that header file `EXIT_FAILURE` and `EXIT_SUCCESS` are defined as:

```
#define EXIT_FAILURE    1       /* Failing exit status.  */
#define EXIT_SUCCESS    0       /* Successful exit status.  */
```

Which is in accordance with typical behaviour of UNIX programs.  `man type` is also useful here, since `type` is a [POSIX command](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696899/utilities/type.html):

```
EXIT STATUS
       The following exit values shall be returned:

        0    Successful completion.

       >0    An error occurred.
```

Therefore yes, returning 1 for failure in `type` is the correct and expected bahaviour.

Moreover, using `EXIT_FAILURE` and `EXIT_SUCCESS` in every `return` instead of the rather confusing `return 1` and `return false` would be better.

---

### if

`if` evaluates the return value of the command passed to it in the following fashion: if the command returns `0` it considers it as true and executes the `then` block; if the command returns something that is not `0` the `else` block is executed (given that that block exists).

Therefore your `type` (returning 0 for success and 1 for failure) shall work as expected in:

```
if type less > /dev/null
then
    echo less exists
else
    echo no less we need to use more
fi
```

---

One more thing, in your code i'm worried about this part:

```
if ((curr_path = malloc(strlen(path) + sizeof(argv[1]))) != NULL) {
    if (curr_path == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "malloc failed!\n");

    }
```

That second `if` has no chance of being true, ever.  You can only get inside the outer block if `curr_path != NULL` and you're testing for `curr_path == NULL`.  I believe that you want this instead:

```
if ((curr_path = malloc(strlen(path) + sizeof(argv[1]))) != NULL) {
    ...  /* the actual path matching */
}
else {
    fprintf(stderr, "malloc failed!\n");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From `help type` in a `bash` shell:

> ```
> type: type [-afptP] name [name ...]
>     Display information about command type.
>
>     For each NAME, indicate how it would be interpreted if used as a
>     command name.
>     ...
>     Exit Status:
>     Returns success if all of the NAMEs are found; fails if any are not found.
> ```